# How to dark the background?

Tags: jquery, html, css, background, background-image

I set a very big background image on my website. This is my code :

```
body{
background-image: url(../images/front/bg.jpg);
background-position: center center;
background-size:cover;
padding:0;
margin:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

I want to create a very smooth black curtain on it when an element is selected to display its text or image. please look at this [ADDRESS](http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/45239.html) for demonstration. when you click on any of the menus the background gets darker. how do I can implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with pseudo elements to the body, like this:

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

body
{
    background-image: url(http://www.placehold.it/1000x800);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    position: relative;
}

body.dark:after
{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Here is a demo
http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/sv4yu/

Edit here is an version using CSS transitions: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/sv4yu/1/

```
body:after
{
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:-1;
}

body.dark:after
{
     background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

You may also just put a transition on the opcacity of the pseudo element.

Comment: It all just about helping others :). Don't worry

Comment: Do you know how to animate this effect?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

### HTML:

```
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

### CSS:

```
body{
    background-image: url(../images/front/bg.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size:cover;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

body > div {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background: #000;
    opacity:0.4;
}
```

You can put your content inside the body, in another div with `top:0` `left:0`. Using `opacity` property, you can create a transition. Would this work?

Comment: I want to dark the background image not the content. the `div` is content

Comment: You can put your content inside the body, in another div

Comment: i upvoted your answer because our attemps are pretty similar. You had the right idea. Just wanted to assure, that i did not copy from you, i was busy preparing the jsFiddle demo.

Answer (score 1):

What they are doing on the site is swapping [this image](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_45239/img/bg_pic1.jpg) with [this one](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_45239/img/bg_pic2.jpg)

this can be acheived with jQuery with something like :

```
$('img').attr('src','newImg.jpg');
```

and possibly a css transition to slow the effect

Comment: you are right but it is much more effective if I do this thing with coding